# Tizen wearable emulator not launching

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-emulator

I'm trying to develop a app to my smartwatch that running Tizen OS.

I've followed all the instructions of installing the system to run, and the Tizen emulator is not lunching, without any error message...either with only trying to lunch the Emulator Manager.

Here some images from my visual studio try:

[image]

after clicking that button it seems like its going to run... and nothing.

No error:

[image]

and evething is installed correctly with the package manage:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could You check if emulator starts from Tools>Tizen>Emulator Manager ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that in mistake I added a JAVA_HOME variable to jdk instead of jre,
after I've changed to jre it works correctly.

It should look somthing like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the tool path was set properly?
(Tools > Options > Tizen > Tools)
Tool path should be set properly and check icon should be shown.